# How can I make Ctrl+Del in Notepad on windows 7 delete just one word like in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, ctrl

I work in notepad on windows 7 and windows 10 but I noticed that the Ctrl+Del shortcut behaves differently in each system. Can I make the shortcut in the notepad on windows 7 delete only the next word?

Comment: With autohotkey yes

Comment: I have autohotkey and I use it enormously, but I cannot seem to find this function.

Comment: How would you do it with shortcuts? Ctrl + right arrow key. Then Ctrl +shift+right arrow key. Delete. This probably won't work if there is punctuation

Comment: As I said in my question I would like to make it work with the same shortcut, ie. Ctrl+Del. I am more looking for a script or code of some kind.

Comment: *"I am more looking for a script or code of some kind.*" - Shortcuts can be scripted in AutoHotkey.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are looking for a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For AutoHotkey, you may wish to try:

```
^Delete::
    Send ^+{Right}
    Send {Delete}
```

Where:

- `^Delete` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
- `^+{Right}` is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
- `{Delete}` is <kbd>Delete</kbd>

**Notes**

- This script will override the normal behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.
- These commands will delete newlines, whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> in Notepad doesn't do this.
- Certain characters (such as `-`) may be treated specially (for instance, *twentieth-century* would be removed as *twentieth-* and *century*).
- If your cursor is located in the middle of a word, the letters after that position plus the next word will be removed. However, this is similar to how <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> operates normally in Windows 7.

---

*AutoHotkey References*

- *[List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)*
- *[Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm)*

---